# Oracle SQL query, getting a a maximum of a sum

Tags: sql, oracle

Hey, guys. I'm struggling to solve one query, just cant get around it.

Basically, I got a some tables from data mart :

```
 DimTheatre(TheatreId(PK), TheatreNo, Name, Address, MainTel);
 DimTrow(TrowId(PK), TrowNo, RowName, RowType);
 DimProduction(ProductionId(PK), ProductionNo, Title, ProductionDir, PlayAuthor);
 DimTime(TimeId(PK), Year, Month, Day, Hour);
 TicketPurchaseFact( TheatreId(FK), TimeId(FK), TrowId(FK),
 PId(FK), TicketAmount);
```

The thing I'm trying to achieve in oracle is - I need to retrieve the most popular row type in each theatre by value of ticket sale

Thing I'm doing now is :

```
SELECT dthr.theatreid, dthr.name, max(tr.rowtype) keep(dense_rank last order 
by tpf.ticketamount), sum(tpf.ticketamount) TotalSale
FROM TicketPurchaseFact tpf, DimTheatre dthr, DimTrow tr
WHERE dthr.theatreid = tpf.theatreid
GROUP BY dthr.theatreid, dthr.name;
```

It does give me the output, but the 'TotalSale' column is totally out of place, it gives much way higher numbers than they should be.. How could I approach this issue :) ?

Comment: It looks like you are missing a join between TicketPurchaseFact and DimTrow table. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yeah I was missing that. Now I realized that my 'TotalSales' gives a combined number of sales for all rowtypes in each theatre and I only need to output only the highest rowtype

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how MAX() KEEP () would help your case if I understand the problem correctly. But the below approach should work:

```
SELECT x.theatreid, x.name, x.rowtype, x.total_sale
FROM
    (SELECT z.theatreid, z.name, z.rowtype, z.total_sale, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY z.theatreid, z.name ORDER BY z.total_sale DESC) as popular_row_rank
    FROM
        (SELECT dthr.theatreid, dthr.name, tr.rowtype, SUM(tpf.ticketamount) as total_sale
        FROM TicketPurchaseFact tpf, DimTheatre dthr, DimTrow tr
        WHERE dthr.theatreid = tpf.theatreid AND tr.trowid = tpf.trowid
        GROUP BY dthr.theatreid, dthr.name, tr.rowtype) z
    ) x
WHERE x.popular_row_rank = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the row type per theatre with the highest ticket amount. So join purchases and rows and then aggregate to get the total per rowtype. Use `RANK` to rank your row types per theatre and stay with the best ranked ones. At last join with the theatre table to get the theatre name.

```
select
  theatreid,
  t.name,
  tr.trowid
from
(
  select 
    p.theatreid, 
    r.rowtype, 
    rank() over (partition by p.theatreid order by sum(p.ticketamount) desc) as rn
  from ticketpurchasefact p
  join dimtrow r using (trowid)
  group by p.theatreid, r.rowtype
) tr
join dimtheatre t using (theatreid)
where tr.rn = 1;
```